# Combining dozens of single GeoTIFFs (4.096x4.096px) made with Ortho4Xp to 1 huge GeoTIFF with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am creating virtual airfields via aerial photography for the simulator X-Plane 12.

I create my airfields over aerial photographs, which I have created so far with QGIS. The disadvantage of this method: The photos are gigantic with 1,5 -1,8 GB.

I have now found another simulator-friendly application with Ortho4XP, which gives me as a result many tiles in the format 4,096x4,096 px, but which I now want to merge into one large GeoTIFF.

Through a little research I came across your homepage today.

Unfortunately I am not so familiar with QGIS, because I don't know if GeoTIFFs from an external source can be merged to a large GeoTIFF in QGIS.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Try combining the rasters using [Build Virtual Raster](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_miscellaneous/buildvirtualraster.html) or [Merge](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_miscellaneous/merge.html)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It's unclear what home page you are referencing. We are not a discussion board; instead we use a Focused question/Best answer model. Questions here are expected to contain a demonstration of due dilligence (an attempt to complete the task, and a indication of the problem encountered). Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: A simpler solution might be [gdal_merge](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html)

Comment: If you have a large amount of files you can use a vrt - https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html